# WPF Window Displays Smaller Than Requested

Tags: c#, wpf, size

I'm trying to display a borderless window that fills the full screen across all monitors.  I have the follow basic application:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
namespace BlackScreen
{
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
      App app = new App();
      Window window = new Window();

      window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

      window.Top = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
      window.Left = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
      window.Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
      window.Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;

      window.Show();
      app.MainWindow = window;
      app.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

All of the values from `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenX` are correct for the bounds of the virtual screen which represents all of the monitors.  However, the window is shown 6 pixels away from the left edge of the left monitor and 6 pixels away from the right edge of the right monitor, as well as 6 pixels above the taskbar (instead of over it).  Adding the `WindowStyle.Maximized` style to the window doesn't help because then it maximizes itself on only one monitor.  I need the window to be "maximized" across all monitors.

Running the above code on a system with only one monitor results in the exact same behaviour where the window is smaller than the requested dimensions.

Comment: What you set `WindowStyle` and `AllowsTransparency` of the Window?

Answer (score 0):

I only have one monitor to work on right now, but adding this line seems to remove the pixel gap.

```
window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
```